# How to Post and Access Information in a Many to Many Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many

If I have the following models set up, is this the appropriate way to add an attribute :foo in the Authorship table that is specific to that relationship and no others?

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :books, :through => :authorships
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :authors, :through => :authorships
end

class Authorship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :foo

  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :book
end
```

What query would return that :foo attribute, or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is entirely appropriate to add attributes to the intermediate model when using `has_many :through`. It's one of the primary reasons to use that pattern instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Aside from what you've shown (`attr_accessible`), you also need to actually add the attribute to the table via migration:

```
class AddFooToAuthorships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :authorships, :foo, :text
  end
end
```

As for the query... I suppose it depends what you're trying to do. `@book.authorships.pluck(:foo)` would return all the values of `foo` on authorships associated with a particular book, for instance.

Comment: I had already done the migration, I just wasn't sure how to actually access the information, or if it was the right method of storing the information.  Your answer provided all the clarity that I needed, Thank you!